# Mapreduce job history server and yarn web UIs do not respect HTTPS_ONLY policy

Tags: hadoop, ssl, https, hadoop-yarn

I am using hadoop 2.7.2 and have configured HTTPS for yarn and job history server web UIs but the UIs are still served as HTTP and not HTTPS.

I have set up key and trust stores and configuring ssl-server.xml and ssl-client.xml. In addition to that, I have put the following properties in mapred-site.xml using ambari:

```
mapreduce.jobhistory.http.policy=HTTPS_ONLY
mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.https.address=JHS:19889
mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address=JHS:19889
```

When I access the https url https://JHS:19889, I receive the following error:

```
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

The above error is because the job history server is listening for http connections and not https.

When I access the same url with http i.e. http://JHS:19889, I can see the job history server web ui. Same thing happens for yarn's resource manager web UI after having made the following configuration:

```
yarn.http.policy=HTTPS_ONLY
yarn.log.server.url=https://JHS:19889/jobhistory/logs
yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.https.address=RM:8090
yarn.nodemanager.webapp.https.address=0.0.0.0:8090
```

How can I make the yarn and job history server web UIs make available on HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Map Reduce and YARN are part of the Hadoop project so to enable SSL you need to turn on SSL in Hadoop in the core-site.xml.

hadoop.ssl.enabled=true

Then there are some more settings (search for hadoop.ssl) that you might need but that's the main one.

Comment: `hadoop.ssl.enabled` is already set to `true` but the job history server still runs on HTTP while using the `mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.https.address` address and port.

Comment: Did you set hadoop.ssl.server.conf to point to your ssl-server.xml and hadoop.ssl.client.conf to point to your ssl-client.xml in the core-site.xml?

Comment: Yes I did so. HDFS webui https is working fine which uses the same property to find the ssl-server and ssl-client files.

Comment: One thing to help debug is set mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address to a different port than the HTTPS.  Looking at the server code, this shouldn't matter but something to try.  Did you see anything in the Job History server logs or the RM logs?  Start by searching for "org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to".  For my setup, I see "Started SslSocketConnectorSecure" after that.